# Manage Camera video stream with MatLab

Tags: matlab, camera, decode

I can receive from the camera a packet that contains information about the frame. So, I know its size. The rest of the packet is an array of bytes (uint8).

I would like to know how to manage this packet of bytes and how to decode it in order to get a frame. I know from the header that the frame can be I-frame or P-frame and that its size is 640x360. The encoding can be set to H264 or MP4. I'm working with MatLab script, which is an M-file. If MatLab cannot manage this array of bytes directly, I would like to know how a byte stream works, to be able to re-assamble the frame myself.

Comment: Have a look at the [`VideoReader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html) class.

Comment: it is not useful for me, i receive a bytestream of a frame and i want to decode it directly, I am working with ardrone 2.0 and i have to manage the live video. I see matlab is not able to manage that so is there any dynamic library or function that i can implement in matlab to decode directly? I have use ffmpeg and it works but it forces me to save in a file and then it converts the file in another file format,  but it takes so much time, about 0,12ms and i would like to make it in 0,03ms aproximately. So the question again is if there's any function implementable in matlab to decode directly.

Comment: If you can get it to work in ffmpeg, you can access ffmpeg from MATLAB using the dos() function. There are probably settings you can configure in ffmpeg to make it faster. For instance, you may be able to more quickly copy the video stream without converting it.